# Sections of a fibration in intersections of quadrics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quadrics, projective-geometry, complete-intersection, birational-geometry

Suppose that we have a smooth variety $X$ of dimension $n$ that fibers (a flat morphism) over a curve $Y$, and s.t. the fibers of $X \to Y$ are all complete interesections of two quadric hypersurfaces of dimension $n$.

Suppose that generically the quadrics are smooth and the singular ones have at most corank 1.

It is easy to see that such an object always has a rational section Y->X. Does it always have a *regular* section? Maybe for $n$ big enough? By regular I mean a section with no intersection with the singular locus of the fibers.

Comment: Do you want the quadric hypersurfaces to assemble into a flat family, or do you just want (geometric? complex?) fibers to be isomorphic to such an intersection?

Comment: Can you count the rational sections? If there is a family of them, the answer is presumably yes, no?

Comment: Yes, I want a flat family of quadrics over a ruled surface $S\to Y$, whose relative intersection gives $X$

Answer (score 1):

As long as the fibers have large enough dimension, they are rationally connected.  Then something stronger than what you want follows from the comb smoothing technique developed by Mori, Koll\'ar and others (and explained in Koll\'ar's book Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties) and the Graber-Harris-Starr (GHS).  Once you know that you have a section (GHS), that X is smooth, and that the fibers are rationally connected, then you can find a section through any specified finite number of points in (different, obviously) smooth fibers.  I first typed too quickly (thanks Artie) - the image of the section is automatically contained in the smooth locus of the map.  The complete intersection of two quadrics in P^4 is Fano, so rationally connected (anything of higher dimensional will also be)

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb, but I don't quite follow. You say "Once you know that you have a section..." and conclude that you can find a section avoiding the singular locus of the fibers. But a section can never intersect the singular locus of a fiber, because at such a point the differential of f fails to be surjective. Am I missing something?

(On the other hand, because of rational connectedness, Graber--Harris--Starr implies that there is always section.)

Comment: very cool. is all this explained in Kollar's book? for instance is it easy to see what is the "large enough" dimension?

Comment: Yes, sorry Artie - I typed too quickly - answer amended.

Comment: Actually it is Fano if n>2, since if n=2 it is an elliptic curve. Anyway, thanks a lot, very interesting!

Comment: Actually, I am probably very ignorant, but why shouldn't the section meet the points with non-surjective differential?

Comment: Just to expand slightly on Artie's comment: if $C$ is a section, then $C.F=1$ for all fibers $F$. If $F$ is singular at $P$ with multiplicity $m$ and $C$ passes through $P$, then the local intersection number $(C.F)_P$ is at least $m$. Then $1\ge m$, contradiction.

Comment: @Olob: inkspot gives one argument. A more elementary one is as follows: suppose $π:X \rightarrow Y$ is the fibration, and $s:Y \rightarrow X$ a section. By definition his means π∘s is the identity map of Y, which implies that dπ must be surjective at any point in the image of the section (since the differential of the identity on Y factors as dπ∘ds). But now at a point p of X, the kernel of dπ is precisely the tangent space at that point to the fibre F containing p. If F is singular at p, the dimension of the tangent space TF_p is greater than dim F=dim X-dim Y=dim $T_pX$-dim $T_{f(p)}Y$... 

Comment: ...so the differential $d\pi(p)$ cannot be surjective. (By the way, replace f by $\pi$ at the end of the previous comment.)